# Hg analog for git log --merges --pretty=format:"%H"

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial

Is where any analog of command git log --merges --pretty=format:"%H" but for hg? To see all hash of merge commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found command hg log --only-merges --template "{node}\n"

Comment: you can also use the more general way and filter for revsets instead of learning single flags: `hg log -r"merge()" --template "{node}\n"`. Check `hg help revsets` for all ways you can filter the changesets

Comment: @Vova Since you solved the problem by yourself, you can mark it as answer. And it will help other who have similar questions.